# Problemas al reiniciar nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, nginx

estoy configurando passenger + nginx en una instancia ec2. Cuando ya he configurado todo y corro el comando `/usr/bin/ruby2.5` me retorna el siguiente error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Cuando corro posteriormente el comando del error `systemctl status nginx.service`:

```
nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-12-29 01:54:05 UTC; 5min ag
 Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 4051 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 -
Process: 3875 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s r
Process: 3972 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code
Process: 4052 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process 
Main PID: 3998 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 29 01:54:05 ip-172-31-13-190 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web serv
Dec 29 01:54:05 ip-172-31-13-190 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web ser
Dec 29 01:54:05 ip-172-31-13-190 nginx[4052]: nginx: [emerg] invalid number of a
Dec 29 01:54:05 ip-172-31-13-190 nginx[4052]: nginx: configuration file /etc/ngi
Dec 29 01:54:05 ip-172-31-13-190 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exit
Dec 29 01:54:05 ip-172-31-13-190 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result '
Dec 29 01:54:05 ip-172-31-13-190 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance
```

Cuando corro luego el comando `journalctl -xe`:

```
 -- Subject: Unit nginx.service has failed
 -- Defined-By: systemd
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 -- 
 -- Unit nginx.service has failed.
 -- 
 -- The result is RESULT.
 Dec 29 01:59:50 ip-172-31-13-190 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Direc
 -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
 -- Defined-By: systemd
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 -- 
 -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
 Dec 29 01:59:50 ip-172-31-13-190 systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Direct
 -- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
 -- Defined-By: systemd
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 -- 
 -- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
 -- 
 -- The start-up result is RESULT.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El log que estás compartiendo está cortado. Donde sale `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of a`, eso es un `invalid number of arguments in...` y ahí está la clave de tu error... en la parte que no estás mostrando. Ahí debería salir la línea específica del archivo donde está el error, que al parecer estás pasando la cantidad de parámetros incorrectos a un comando o algo así. Si compartes el código de tu configuración en vez de un pantallazo también ayudaría.

Comment: Hola , mm la consola me mostraba así el log.. voy a revisarlo que raro. De la configuración de server? (La última imagen)

Comment: Buena @AlterLagos al final pasaba que tenia repetiva la directiva "root", gracias!

Comment: falta el punto y coma (;) al final de la línea de la directiva `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final, gracias a la ayuda en la busqueda @Alter Lagos, pude percatarme que la directiva `root` estaba duplicada mas abajo creando el conflicto con la agrega en la configuracion:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /usr/bin/ruby2.5/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.5;
    
    root /var/www/html; <- Aqui estaba la duplicada
}
```